# Is there a control in WPF similar to the Visual Studio toolbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm writing an application using WPF, and I need to make something that looks like the Visual Studio toolbox (please see pic). What control should I use for this?

[image: Visual Studio toolbox]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like [`AvalonDock`](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/).

[image]

Comment: yes thanks that is what im looking for. i downloaded and install it but i dont know how to use

Answer (score 2):

Use an **expander control** for the expandable headers.

The content of every expander can be a **ListBox** with a special *ItemTemplate* (with image an text).

http://wpf.codeplex.com/ has additional controls to help you.

greetz,
knom.

Answer (score 1):

You would use either a ListView or a TreeView.
Both controls allow you to write templates for your items, the difference is that the TreeView is hierarchical. Which control you use depends on the structure of your data, but you will proabably use the TreeView.

For your TreeView you will have to define two item templates, one for the root items and one for the child items. It should be quite easy, but it depends on your data of course.