# How can I have a solution based layout for my WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

I am coding a C# forms application where I am wanting to have the layout of my application to have a similar style of the Visual Studio 2013 layout. By this, I mean to have a property grid at the lower right of the screen, a solution explorer to the top right of the screen, tabs for the content and a toolbox.

Do I need to use a FlowLayout control for this? I have previously found some sample code with this layout all coded to use as a template, however I cannot seem to find this after doing a search. What is the correct terminology for this layout style? Also, is there a Microsoft sample for this?

Here is an image of what I am looking for:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Visual Studio is a **complex** layout, and isn't achieved with a single control...but you're looking for a [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx).  That will allow you to create rows/columns and specify how those rows/columns should resize in relation to each other.  Those relationships can be absolute sized, auto-sized, or as a percentage of each other.  Within the cells of the TableLayoutPanel, you can place controls, other containers, or even nested TableLayoutPanels.  Controls within can span rows/columns as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following readily made controls from Visual Studio:

1. `System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid` for the properties
2. `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView` for the solution explorer
3. For the toolbox you will need to create a custom-control, with search box and dropdown tabbing of pages. See making of custom controls here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6hws6h2t(v=vs.100).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2016/Writing-your-Custom-Control-step-by-step

Comment: Is a FlowLayout control what I am needing for this design style?

Comment: `FlowLayoutPanel` is a container that wraps child controls. This makes it easier to dynamically layout and arranged controls horizontally and vertically. If this serves your purpose then you can use this.

Comment: Is there a Microsoft sample for the solution based layout?

Comment: Might not be exactly what you want but you can check a WPF solution similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603001/is-there-a-control-in-wpf-similar-to-the-visual-studio-toolbox