# what control should I use for this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In visual studio the toolbox design is like

[image]

when you click on,sub items are shown .
what is its name ,and how can I have one ?

I want to use this in windows form not wpf

Comment: Are we talking in WinForms or WPF?

Comment: It's a WPF control ... Same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603001/is-there-a-control-in-wpf-similar-to-the-visual-studio-toolbox

Comment: @Moumit AvalonDock is about the "fly out" it has nothing to do with the expand/collapse functionality which is what this question asks for.

Comment: I want to use it windows app not WPF

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just add random controls to a `form`?

Answer (score 3):

It is commonly called a Tree View. In C#, there are two built in classes. Depending on which UI framework you are using, you would use either:

- [System.Windows.Controls.TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx) (WPF)
- [System.Windows.Forms.TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx) (WinForms)

Answer (score 0):

Do a menuStrip. Drag a menuStrip on your form. Then add what you want. Click each item you add then code what the item does.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11688348)

Comment: @codedByMi it was the answer he was looking for. And if your going to Answer a question then it goes right were I put it in the Answer box. I am not sure what you don't understand about the Answer. It tells him what it is MenuStrip and how to get it. I understand if you just get triggr happy, and randomly comment on answer with out reading. Read first then understand. Then if your trigger happy, leave your comments to yourself, about my answers.